# Laravel Carbon get passed years relative to current time

Tags: laravel

I need to show the passed years like `5.6` years with a given date `$model->created_at`

What I tried so far is

```
$dt     = Carbon::now();
echo $dt->diffForHumans($model->created_at); 1 month ago
```

how to show date only like 5.6 years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `Carbon::floatDiffInRealYears` to get exactly the different,

and `Carbon::diffInYears` to get the rounded result of the previous method

```
$dt     = Carbon::now();
echo $dt->floatDiffInRealYears($model->created_at);
```

Comment: you can use number_format($dt,1) see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: $dt     =  Carbon::now();   
                $years_passed = round($dt->floatDiffInRealYears($model->created_at),1);